# Why do I get an unhashable type 'list' error when converting a list to a set and back

Tags: python, list, set, duplicates, typeerror

Like many other questions on here, I'm attempting to remove duplicates from a list. However, when I execute code that other answers claim work I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

on the following line of code:

```
total_unique_words = list(set(total_words))
```

Does anyone know a possible solution to this problem? Is this because in most cases the original structure isn't a list?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the actual code you're using to create `total_words`. I suspect you think this should be a list of strings, when in fact it's probably a list of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`total_words` must contain sublists for this error to occur.

Consider:

```
>>> total_words = ['red', 'red', 'blue']
>>> list(set(total_words))
['blue', 'red']
>>> total_words = ['red', ['red', 'blue']] # contains a sublist
>>> list(set(total_words))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Probably more likely `[['red', 'red', 'blue']]` - the whole list is a sublist.

Comment: @MarkRansom:  That's a fair possibility.  I'll leave it to your comment to be the clarification.

Comment: Yeah that was it, seems so obvious now. Thanks!